# Returning Multiple Views in Fragment?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, android-view

I am inflating my XML through my Fragments Java file as usual:

```
public class FragmentJava extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_drive_layout, container, false);
```

and then of course

```
return rootView;}}
```

This works fine, however, I am also trying to utilize a Syncfusion library to get gauges on my screen, and that requires me to `setContentView()`, which won't work with Fragments, so I've just resolved to `return` the gauges that I'm building like this:

```
//Create the gauge:

SfCircularGauge circularGauge = new SfCircularGauge(getActivity());
ArrayList<CircularScale> _circularScales = new ArrayList<CircularScale>();
CircularScale circularScale = new CircularScale();

// etc. etc., other settings...

circularGauge.setCircularScales(_circularScales);
```

and then I simply return this instance of the Circular Gauge:

`return circularGauge;`

instead of

`return rootView;`

Obviously, I lose all of my XML elements by doing so and I am left with the gauge overlaid on the activity which is a plain `RelativeLayout` with a background color rather than all the amazing graphic elements in my XML ;(

I am not great with Java, but is there any way to return the rootView of the XML and then the gauges over the XML?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Syncfusion, but you should be able to do this call on the activity level in the onCreate method.  Load the resulting array into a public member variable on the activity.  Then in your fragment's onCreateView (or wherever in the fragment), you can access it like so:

```
((MyCustomActivity)getActivity()).mCircularScales;
```

Comment: I just tried to implement this...`mCircularScales` would be a class in the Activity file right?

Comment: Not a class but a member variable.  You would define it outside of your methods like so:

    MyCustomActivity extends Activity {
        private ArrayList<CircularScale> mCircularScales;

Comment: I understand, but I'm still unsure how I would implement that over my XML layout. If I access `mCircularScales` from my Fragment, I don't know how to include that in the `rootView` that I am returning for the XML.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to approach this, it all depends on the use.

1. If you want the gauges to be part of your fragment you can simply add the custom library widgets into your layout in the xml or programatically.
   By doing so your fragment should manage the gauges.
2. If you want the gauges to remain afloat while you switch between fragments you can add the gauges to your root view (in the activity) which holds the fragments' container (either in the xml or programatically).
   By doing so your activity should manage the gauges. If you should pass data from the fragments some sort of "setGaugesData" method created in the activity and invoked by the fragments should be handy.

Good luck.